# Deleting update cache

Tags: package-management

How can I clear the list of updates and softwares (from an ubuntu download server)  created when `sudo apt-get update` is run for the first time (after the download server is selected)?

I do not want to delete the downloaded .deb files just the update cache created by `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: You mean, you want to install packages even though it does not match (outdated) to the currently updated version in apt-get's list, right? And to do that, you need to revert back the list?

Comment: I want to restore the status when `sudo apt-get update` was never run (for a download server). btw, I don't want to delete any .deb.

Comment: I think that you can't do that, since "sudo apt-get update" already made modifications (overwrite) to your original list of packages. But you can do that if you have the old list files and use it to replace your current lists.

Comment: Where are the list files? Then I'll delete them.

Comment: Don't! It will break your system, that files are essential for apt, they contains all package repository list and deleting them would make your apt to malfunction.

Comment: Aren't they automatically created when `sudo apt-get update` is run again? btw, if so I'll copy and replace them from a LiveCD Ubuntu temporarily run. Where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Downloaded package lists are in:

  ```
  /var/lib/apt/lists/
  ```

  **Reference:** [The Debian Administrator's Handbook - The apt-cache Command](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/sect.apt-cache.html)
- You can get that easily with `strace` command:

  ```
  strace -e trace=open apt-get update
  ```

  Meaning: trace file `open` system calls of `apt-get update`
- **strace - trace system calls and signals**

  > **strace** is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and debugging tool.  System administrators, diagnosticians and trouble-shooters will find it invaluable for solving  problems with programs for which the source is not readily available since they do not need to be recompiled in order to trace them.
  >
  > Students, hackers and the overly-curious will find that a great deal can be learned about a system and its system calls by racing even ordinary programs.  And programmers will find that since system calls and signals  are events that happen at the user/kernel interface, a close examination of this boundary is very useful for bug isolation, sanity checking and attempting to capture race conditions.

  Usage: `strace [trace_options] command [args]`

  So:

  1. `apt-get update` is the regular command used to update/download packages lists.
  2. `strace` will run `apt-get update` and trace its system calls.
  3. `-e trace=open` strace with default options will log all system calls. But we don't need that. So with this option strace will trace only file opening calls/operations.

  Reference: [`man strace`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/strace.1.html)

  Output sample:

  `strace -e trace=open apt-get update > /dev/null`

  ```
  open("/tmp/fileutl.message.WrgKYY", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 17
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release", O_RDONLY) = 19
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release", O_RDONLY) = 17
  open("/tmp/fileutl.message.TrxfHl", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 17
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release", O_RDONLY) = 19
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release", O_RDONLY) = 17
  open("/tmp/fileutl.message.gaI8CI", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 17
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release", O_RDONLY) = 19
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release", O_RDONLY) = 17
  open("/tmp/fileutl.message.fcWaM5", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 17
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_Release", O_RDONLY) = 19
  open("/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_Release", O_RDONLY) = 17
  ```

Comment: what does `strace -e trace=open apt-get update` do? Does it update the list?

Comment: @user69453, `apt-get update` updates lists, as `strace` is just a debugging tools that will start `apt-get update`; Yes, the complete cmd will do same (strace does not affect the work of apt-get). I have updated answer

Comment: If I delete all contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` will `strace -e trace=open apt-get update` fix it?

Comment: @user69453. yes, `sudo apt-get update` will be enough (No need to use `strace`)